# Google Maps like Detail View

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface

I try to rebuild the Detail View on the bottom of the Android Google Maps app.
So if I select a item a detail bar (view) appears at the bottom of the screen. If I push it or swipe it up I see more details.

Is there any open source library available? Or how can I build such a view?

Comment: Do you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution but the [SlidingUpPanelLayout](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) project provides the majority of the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such library, but you could reverse engineer it.

1. Get the coordinate for touch/long touch from the map.
2. Get the data from Google Place APi.
3. Create view that would be placed at the bottom (preferably `ViewPager` without fragments, but views. See `PagerAdapter`)
4. Swipe between views to show relevant information from Google Places API (See: Places detail API section)

Hope it helps.